# Execute jQuery function only one time for entire site?

Tags: jquery

At the top of the page([phory](http://phoryapp.com)) I have this blue div showing on jQuery(document).ready()
After the user clicks the "x" it disappears, but then it appears again after he comes back to the homepage after visiting some other pages.
I need this element to stay invisible after the first time the user closes it.
How can I achieve this?
I will really appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: set localstorage variable/cookie to make the descision of show/hide.

Comment: A little more info on  how to do this?

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Using localstorage:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("showonce") === null) {
     //show div here
     localStorage.setItem('showonce', true);  
}
```